# PermitRootLogin yes seems not to be working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, root

I need to SFTP with my IDE, that's why I set `PermitRootLogin yes` in sshd_config file. But it's not working I still need to sudo after logging in with password.
Here is my full settings file content:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods password
AllowUsers root
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
After changes I restart ssh service, so that's not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a password for root

```
sudo passwd root
```

then you can login with root.

After that, sftp needs also some settings to allow users *x*, *y* and *z* to log in.

See [this explanation for the setup](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-sftp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-with-vsftpd)

**Note**: this is dangerous to `AllowUsers root` directly in the sshd_config.

You should at least add a domain or an IP address

```
AllowUsers root@example.com
AllowUsers root@1.2.3.4
```

Or you could change your method to use a simple user (if possible).

Also install `fail2ban`, if your ssh port is 22, there is nothing else to do, the ssh login attempts will trigger fail2ban alert that will ban the abusing IPs for some time.